# Trying to get the relative difference between two groups with negative values

Tags: group-differences, mean

I have two groups A and B which have few duplicating values.

So the overall data point is less than the summation data points from group A and B

It's because group A and B data are simply taken out from the overall data.

The group A values are:

```
 0.008385618
 0.003966736
 -0.000549212
 -0.0161096
 -0.008572115
 0.008385618
 0.003966736
 -0.000549212
 -0.0161096
 -0.008572115
 -0.013914553
```

Then group B values are:

```
 -0.008572115
 -0.013914553
 -0.017750119
 -0.021683121
 -0.022425818
 -0.022540774
 -0.022554941
 -0.022357409
 -0.017750119
 -0.021683121
 -0.022425818
 -0.022540774
 -0.022554941
 -0.022357409
```

The overall data which does not have duplicating values from group A and B is as follows:

```
 0.008385618
 0.003966736
 -0.000549212
 -0.0161096
 -0.008572115
 -0.013914553
 -0.017750119
 -0.021683121
 -0.022425818
 -0.022540774
 -0.022554941
 -0.022357409
```

I am trying to get the relative difference of group A from group B.
Currently I used the following formula.

```
 |(group A average - group B average)/(overall data average)| - 1
```

and I get the result of 0.266286801

May I know whether this is correct? If not, may I know what formula should give me the correct answer?

Comment: It seems that you're removing duplicated values, not values that overlap between groups. Can you explain your reason to remove them, or how these duplicates arise? Also, are you planning any significance testing for that difference?

Comment: Yes you are right that I am removing duplicated values (Thanks that I changed my post accordingly). Removing duplicates is essential for my work agenda which will be a long story to explain. Also I already did the significance test for difference using Welch's t test since two groups have different numbers of data.

Comment: I'd use group A mean, not the overall mean, in the denominator - that way you can report something like "...compared to drug A, mean value of parameter X was 23% larger when treating with drug B". Unless you're trying to achieve something different, that is.

Comment: As for the duplicates - fine, just make sure that you are removing duplicates that arise from technical reasons (i.e. apparatus malfunctioned and printed out a measurement twice), not just because you see repeated values on different occasions.

Comment: So would it be |(group A average- group B average)/(group B average)| if finding the relative difference of group A against group B?

Comment: I suppose you mean 'group B' in the denominator if I am correct..?

Comment: The denominator would be mean of the reference group, and corresponding interpretation is then "compared to reference group, the other group mean was [result here] larger/smaller..."   You might also want to move the modulus inside the fraction: `(|mean A| - |mean B|)/|mean B|` to be safe in case the means had opposite signs. Whether a relative difference is at all useful in those situations is doubtful, but that's a topic for a different question.

Comment: What about using (group A average - group B average)/|group B average| to maintain the direction?

Comment: Sorry but when I move the absolute sign inside the brackets I get opposite result and is intuitively wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To comment more on the role of the modulus here - consider three cases:
1) both group means positive, say $\mu_a=2, \mu_b=1$
2) both group means negative, say $\mu_a=-2, \mu_b=-1$
3) means have opposite signs, say $\mu_a=2, \mu_b=-1$

When the signs match, the relative difference is interpretable and formulas are equivalent up to a sign (which you will determine based on your phrasing anyway):

$(\mu_a - \mu_b) / |\mu_b| = (2-1)/|1| = 1$, or
$|(\mu_a - \mu_b) / \mu_b| = |(2-1)/1| = 1$, or
$(|\mu_a| - |\mu_b|) / |\mu_b| = (|2|-|1|)/|1| = 1 \implies $ 100% difference in case 1

$(-2-(-1))/|-1| = -1$, or
$|\frac{-2 - (-1)}{-1}| = 1$, or
$(|-2|-|-1|)/|-1| = 1 \implies $ 100% difference in case 2

However, when the signs are different:

$(2-(-1))/|-1| = 3$, or
$|\frac{2-(-1)}{-1}| = 3$, vs.
$(|2|-|-1|)/|-1| = 1$

Latter formula is simply throwing out the direction information and just gives a relative difference in the magnitude. I presume that's not what you want to do with your data, but I imagine situations where that would be applicable. On the other hand, stating that "2 is 300% larger than -1" would certainly look confusing to me - hence I would advise against using any such derived statistics in case 3).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But for me, saying 2 is 300% larger than -1 interpretation seems more fitting although I am in case 2 now.